# When using HornetQ for audit logging to requests to DB, start log entry is not always committed before end log entry

Tags: hibernate, jboss, jboss7.x, messaging, hornetq

I have an application that is using JBoss AS 7, Hibernate, and HornetQ. We use HornetQ for handling the logging of all requests coming into the application. As a request comes in, we send a "start log entry" message which when consumed, logs a UUID of the request, its start time, and other various data related to the request.  When the request is finished, we send an "end log entry" message, when consumed looks up the starting log entry (with the UUID) from the database, and adds the end time to the request.

The problem that is occurring constantly is the db lookup done in the "end log entry" doesn't find the matching starting entry because the entity manager hasn't actually committed/flushed the starting log entry to the database yet. I need to guarantee that the start log entry is in the database before the end log entry tries to look it up. Any ideas how to do ensure this happens?

Here are the relevant classes we have:

LogFilter.java - this is the filter defined in the web.xml to intercept all requests and log them

```
public class LogFilter implements Filter {
    @Inject
    LoggingService ls;

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
      // do stuff to create the log entry

      try {
        ls.startLogEntry(logEntry);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
      } finally {
          try {
            ls.endLogEntry(logEntry);
          } catch (Exception e2) {
            // log stacktrace to the server logs
          }
      }
   }
}
```

LoggingService.java - the service injected into the LogFilter

```
public class LoggingService {
  private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(LoggingService.class);
  @PersistenceContext(unitName="p1")
  private EntityManager em;

  // find a log entry by its generated uuid when the request started
  public LogEntry getLogEntry(String uuid) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<LogEntry> c = cb.createQuery(LogEntry.class);
    Root<LogEntry> root = c.from(LogEntry.class);

    c.where(cb.equal(root.get(LogEntry_.uuid), uuid));

    TypedQuery<LogEntry> tq = em.createQuery(c);
    return JpaUtil.getSingleResultOrNull(tq);
  }

  // send message to write the log entry without the end time
  public void startLogEntry(LogEntry logEntry) {
    AuditLogProducer.sendLogEntryToQueue(logEntry);
  }

  public void endLogEntry(LogEntry logEntry) {
    if (logEntry != null) {
      logEntry.setRequestEnd(new Date());
      AuditLogProducer.sendLogEntryToQueue(logEntry);
    }
  }
}
```

AuditLogProducer.java - class responsible for sending the messages to the queue

```
public class AuditLogProducer {
  private static final String QUEUE_LOOKUP = "jboss/queue/AuditLogQueue";
  private static final String CONNECTION_FACTORY = "ConnectionFactory";
  private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AuditLogProducer.class);

  public static void sendLogEntryToQueue(LogEntry logEntry) {
    QueueSession session = null;
    QueueConnection connection = null;

    try {
      Context context = new InitialContext();
      QueueConnectionFactory factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup(CONNECTION_FACTORY);
      connection = factory.createQueueConnection();
      session = connection.createQueueSession(false, QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup(QUEUE_LOOKUP);

      QueueSender sender = session.createSender(queue);
      ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage();

      message.setObject(logEntry);
      sender.send(message);
      session.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("problem sending message to queue: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
      if (session != null) {
        try {
          session.close();
          connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

AuditLogConsumer.java - class responsible for consuming messages from the queue

```
@MessageDriven(
  activationConfig={
      @ActivationConfigProperty(
        propertyName="destinationType",
        propertyValue="javax.jms.Queue"
      ), @ActivationConfigProperty(
        propertyName="destination",
        propertyValue="queue/AuditLogQueue"
      )
    }
)
public class AuditLogConsumer implements MessageListener {
  private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AuditLogConsumer.class);

  @Inject
  LogBuilder logBuilder;

  @Inject
  LogPolisher logPolisher;

  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message message) {
    if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
      ObjectMessage msg = (ObjectMessage) message;
      LogEntry logEntry = null;

      try {
        logEntry = (LogEntry) msg.getObject();
      } catch (JMSException e) {
        log.error("Problem retrieving JMS message from the AuditLogQueue: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        return;
      }

      if (logEntry.getRequestEnd() == null) {
        logBuilder.insertLogEntry(logEntry);
      } else {
        logPolisher.updateLogEntry(logEntry);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

LogBuilder.java - class that's solely responsible for merging the log entry into the database - used to be in one class, but broken out in hopes that separating the creation and the update into 2 classes would ensure the start was written to the database on time (didn't end up working)

```
@Singleton
public class LogBuilder {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName="p1")
  private EntityManager em;

  @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void insertLogEntry(LogEntry log) {
    em.merge(log);
    em.flush();
  }
}
```

LogPolisher.java - class solely responsible for finding the start log entry, setting the end time, and merging the new log to the database - newLog.setRequestEnd(requestEnd) fails sometimes when the previous line returns null because it didn't find the start log entry (because it hadn't been written yet).

```
@Singleton
public class LogPolisher {
  private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(LogPolisher.class);
  @Inject
  LoggingService loggingService;

  @PersistenceContext(unitName="p1")
  private EntityManager em;

  @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void updateLogEntry(LogEntry logEntry) {
    Date requestEnd = logEntry.getRequestEnd();

    try {
      LogEntry newLog = loggingService.getLogEntry(logEntry.getUuid());

      newLog.setRequestEnd(requestEnd);
      em.merge(newLog);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

And LogEntry.java is just a plain hibernate bean that I'm not going to waste any more space on here showing its code.

Comment: is that a question or an architecture review? I'm trying to identify where is your question

Comment: check out the 2nd paragraph again. I'm asking how to ensure the entity manager flushes the 1st transaction before the 2nd one takes place

Comment: but to understand that you have to know where the EntityManager comes on the picture. 

Anyways.. the performance here would suck really badly. You are creating a Consumer and a producer every time... why you need messaging then if you are making it synchronous? a database would be better here. If you want real messaging keep the consumer or producer open somewhere.

The fact that you are actually relying on the order of the queue is telling me that you are confusing a message system as a database.

Database=store/retrieve
Messaging=deliver

Answer (score 0):

I didn't initially want to answer this as I am having a bit of difficulty to understand your issue. But I've spotted a few issues that could maybe help you identify your problem.

I - It seems that you are confusing Messaging and Database. it seems obvious but it's a quite common misunderstanding. Messaging is for delivering messages asynchronously. (never store). The fact that you actually need to match the Database with the queue could maybe indicate that there is something wrong there with your architecture.

II - Performance will suck on these producers/ consumers... They are all synchronous as you are creating a consumer or producer every log entry. you should cache your objects and reuse them per thread. that maybe indicates the anti-pattern (i) being used.

III - I'm not sure if XA is being used here but some Transaction Manager (TM) doesn't guarantee the order on which branches are committed first. This is being fixed on newer versions of the Transaction Manager.

IV - you are building a framework (your log tool) using another framework (JPA). Unless you need something that dynamic.. I would use JDBC directly. otherwise you are bound on a framework*framework. It gets complex.. but that's just IMHO.

I'm just attempting to provide you some help here.. even though it doesn't directly answer your question.

Comment: The point of the message queue in this case is to separate the writing of the log entries to the database from the actual web request (let the system write log entries to the database as it can vs holding up the web request waiting on a log entry to be written). With millions of requests hitting the server over the span of a few days, writing/updating logs shouldn't be a bottleneck.

Comment: apparently I took too long to edit my previous comment. Let me start again. Thank you for your answer; more comments follow:

I - The point of the message queue in this case is to separate the writing of the log entries to the database from the actual web request (let the system write log entries to the database as it can vs holding up the web request waiting on a log entry to be written). With millions of requests hitting the server over the span of a few days, writing/updating logs shouldn't hold up a response to the user. I would think this would be a perfect case for using a message queue.

Comment: II - Performance here is actually ok since the Consumer lives in a consumer pool within JBoss. As soon as a consumer is available, it grabs the next message in the message queue. Sending a message to the queue takes between 1 and 4 milliseconds.

III - The issues I'm experiencing here happen regardless of using XA Datasource or regular datasource (Oracle as the backend). I'm interested to see what's being fixed in the TM in the future.

Comment: IV - The logging portion of our app is a tiny piece of the entire system, all which is using JPA. I thought the point of using the JPA spec was to write database interactions to a standard--then regardless of the backend database, as long as it supports JPA, we can swap rather easily.

Comment: But back to the message queue question--messages are guaranteed to be consumed in the same order that they're delivered. I can see this happening in our server logs (jboss). So the question is, if they're being consumed in order, then what is triggered by the message (in our case, we're either inserting or updating a log) should also happen in order in my opinion.  The beauty of a message queue is messages can spawn any type of activity--I'm not sure why upon receiving a message a database entry couldn't be written. Surely I'm not the only one trying to do something like this?

Comment: do you have a single consumer? maybe you have client cache (prefetch) affecting your order on which case you would have to use grouping or consumer-window-size = 0